# Installing PyQT4 or 5 to get pywebview to work on PyCharm in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, webview, pyqt, pycharm

I use Ubuntu and installed the package pywebview in my project interpreter in PyCharm. However, when I tried running a file with an import of webview, I got an error that said I needed to have PyQT4 or 5. For some reason, PyCharm isn't allowing me to install it in the interpreter. I went to my terminal and managed to install PyQT5 there, but the error still shows up even then. What exactly am I supposed to do with all this?

Comment: execute `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt4 python-pyqt5`

Comment: I got this error:E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: execute `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock `

Comment: Most likely you have interrupted the installation of a package unexpectedly.

Comment: I'm getting another error: Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Also, isn't removing the lock dangerous? How do I put the lock back?

Comment: read  this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-when-updating-installing-app

Comment: And putting the lock back to /var/lib/dpkg? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154616/discussion-between-jerry-bi-and-eyllanesc).